# LAMP server - one command?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu, lamp

I've been reading around the last couple of days to figure out virtual machines and LAMP/WAMP/XAMP and everything else....and wanted to ask one question regarding when it comes to installing the apache/SQL/PHP applications - I've just come across the following command:

`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

...does this do the same thing as this whole walk-through that I've been been through a few times (as I'm trying to get Symfony set up)?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: Make yourself comfortable with Vagrant and puphpet.com. That may help a lot and speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from the website you have provided:

To install the **default LAMP stack** in Ubuntu 10.04 and above:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

So, yes. That does the trick.
The rest of the website is when you wish to install just apache2 for example. Or want to setup LAMP in specific ways.

Comment: haha! Typical - yes, that's just one of about 4 walkthroughs that I bookmarked...typically, it's the one with the 'default LAMP stack'... thanks for clarifying :)